# Deletion and Archiving of old data in Microservice system

Tags: c#, sql, database, microservices

I am preparing to implement delete and archive the old data in the current system.

More information about our system.
Architecture: We apply Microservice architecture, Framework: .Net, and Database: SQL.

The requirement is the data deleted in the main table will be stored in the other table with the same schema and we call it an archived table. Of course, data will be deleted based on several criteria.

So based on the requirements, I decided to create a new service and I called it the Data deletion service. I want a service that is a centralized place for data deletion.

I have two approaches below:

1. The function to get and delete data will be implemented on each service. The deletion service just calls the API to get the data to be deleted and store it in the new table, after that the deletion service will call the delete function in each service.  For this approach, we follow the communication between each service, we just make the communication via API. The drawback is a mismatch between interfaces when having an update in the service, hard to control the transaction if some services are involved, and hard to restore data.
2. The Deletion service will connect to the database of each service directly. For this approach, I rely on the advantage of the Entity framework to sync the schema from the main service to the deletion service to update the scheme if needed. Maybe I can control the transaction of the data that will be deleted. I can process the huge of data that will be deleted in this approach because have a bit of a limit when transferring data via API. Easily restore the data when have a problem and do not affect the main service.

Which approach is good? Or are there any topics related to the data deletion in the microservice that I can apply?

Comment: Despite its length, there's very little information in the question. `Microservices` is a fashion term and explains nothing. You have multiple *services*. If they're truly independent, you can back up their data independently. `the data deleted in the main table will be stored in the other table with the same schema and we call it an archived table.` that describes a Temporal table in SQL Server or just a history table in any other database. That's done' with triggers, not with extra services that run several orders of magnitude slower and worse, aren't part of the same transaction.

Comment: Both approaches are bad because the services just aren't services. They're both dealing with the exact same data, at the wrong abstraction level. A service is supposed to perform one ***business** function*. Business functions are never CRUD operations, those are how we implement the storage for the business functions. If you expose the CRUD details as services, who's going to combine them to perform the business function? Yet another service?

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos, I agree with you that the deletion service is not a service. It is like a tool for collecting data in the distributed system after that the data will be deleted and stored in another place. Do you have any ideas or topics that you know for the requirements above? Because I want to delete the old data and store the deleted data for another process like reporting...etc

Comment: It's not a tool for that either, it's a low-level implementation detail found in all real services. `delete the old data and store the deleted data for another process like reporting...etc` these things have little if anything to do with services, they're database concerns. The terms in this case are ETL, Star schemas, replication, change management. If, as I suspect, you want to use DDD concepts and event streaming, the events in question are the *business** events, not the CRUD events.

Comment: Once the real service finishes its job, eg amend an order, perform a transfer or issue a ticket, it could write that *business* event to eg a Kafka or RabbitMQ queue that will be processed by a reporting worker that would update a reporting database or data warehouse. Or an ETL job could run periodically to pull all changes from the service databases, transform them and update the reporting database. The reporting database doesn't care about the tables used by the services themselves, only the actual business events

Comment: Sure, currently, I have applied several ways that you mentioned about reporting. But it is just an example, the main point is nobody wants to lose the data, but we still need to delete it in the main table. I found the appropriate answer for me below. Thank you so much.

Comment: The point is this has nothing to do with a "DELETE" service. I'm saying the same things the other answers are saying, just pushing it further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a microservice architecture, each service has to be responsible for maintaining its own data, in no circumstances should another service be interacting directly with their data.

In a well designed microservice architecture, only a single service (the 'single source of truth') should be able to change data within a particular domain. E.g. the customer service is responsible for maintaining customers. Additions / Changes / Deletions to customers can only be made via this service.

Microservices work best when they're decoupled - so the customer service should be able to enact the change, then publish it for other services to be aware of, not have to chase every other service, keep up to date with their different APIs etc. (how do you stay on top of new services? Maintainability will fail badly beyond a certain scale)

In summary:

1. Your deletion service talking to each api is less than ideal. (you now have to maintain a list of all services which need to delete the data, what payload and url you need to call to delete it, and handle cases where they fail to delete the data)
2. Your deletion service talking directly to each DB is horrendous, avoid at all costs. (you now not only need to know about each service DB, but also keep up with their different schemas too)
3. You should seriously reconsider whether your microservice architecture really makes sense if you're having to propagate data changes directly via API calls, rather than using a publish/subscribe style model. Each service should be decoupled from the others. You should not need a separate service to delete data - it should be built into each service that data from the single source of truth will be added / updated / deleted, with a mechanism for automatically maintaining your data via eventual consistency.

Answer (score 1):

How is this supposed to work if the services uses different databases? Or no database at all? Microservices should be independent, and allowed to handle data in whatever way best fit the service.

For the sake of discussion I will assume you have multiple service all handling different types of data, that all have in common something like backups, database rotation or similar. With the "Deletion Service" providing a central place to view and manage policy.

You could have a API implemented by each service that allows your deletion service to dump, delete and restore data. With the "data" being an opaque blob. You may be able to make this API take a time parameter, or something similar, to specify the data to be dumped or deleted. But chances are that some data is time-independent, and should not be deleted or dumped. If there is any relation between time dependent data and time-independent data you will have a problem.

Or you could have each microservice implement archiving and deletion however it wants to, be it with archive/deleted flags, moving data between tables, making a full db backup or whatever makes sense for the kind of data the service manages. With a common API for control functions.

The last alternative would be to accept that your microservices are not really independent, and use whatever strategy you find most convenient and practical.

Comment: Worse than not-independent. They're the CRUD details used in the implementation of a service, exposed as separate services themselves. Which means yet-another-service will have to combine them now to do the job. I suspect this is misunderstood microservices combined with misunderstood DDD

Comment: Hi JonasH, I have different database for each service and they are independent. So for your answer, the first approach is similar to your explanation.

Comment: @KhanhTran except that if the data is a blob the API should not need to change if the data change. Ofc, the services will need to support restoring old data according to their service contract.

Comment: @KhanhTran In your second suggestion you say "The Deletion service will connect to the database of each service directly", that is a direct violation of service independence.